# AngularJS Array shows all ID of field every time on same index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a static array and I am trying to show a particular field of this array  through `ng-repeat`, but my array shows every time the ID field on single index.

This is what my output screenshot looks like

[image: output screenshot]

You can find my code below,

```
function monthCalendarController($scope, $http, $rootScope, $filter, $location, WebService, CalendarEventService) {
    $scope.eventSelected = function(event) {
        var params = {
            id: event.event.id
        };
        var url = $rootScope.url + '/v1/show_event';
        var token = window.localStorage['token'];
        var result = WebService.makeServiceCallHeader(url, params, $rootScope.POST, token);
        result.then(function(response) {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                CalendarEventService.addEvent(response.data.event);
                $location.path("/calendarEvent");
            } else {
                WebService.showAlert('Problem in Loading');
            }
        }, function(response) {
            console.log('' + JSON.stringify(response));
        });
    };
    $scope.persons = [
        { "id": 1, "name": "A", "select": true }, 
        { "id": 2, "name": "B", "select": true }, 
        { "id": 3, "name": "C", "select": true }, 
        { "id": 4, "name": "D", "select": true }, 
        { "id": 5, "name": "E", "select": true }, 
        { "id": 6, "name": "F", "select": true }, 
        { "id": 0, "name": "G", "select": true }
    ];
    console.log($scope.counts);
    $scope.selectDate = function(date) {
        $scope.selectedDate = date.date;
        $scope.showEventsDiv = true;
    };
};
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="monthCalendarController">
    <table class="table table-bordered monthview-datetable monthview-datetable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ng-show="showWeeks" class="calendar-week-column text-center">#
                </th>
                <th ng-repeat="label in labels track by $index" class="text-center">
                    <small>{{label}}
                    </small>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index">
                <td ng-show="showWeeks" class="calendar-week-column text-center">
                    <small>
                        <em>{{ weekNumbers[$index] }}</em>
                    </small>
                </td>
                <td ng-repeat="dt in row track by dt.date" 
                    class="monthview-dateCell" 
                    ng-click="select(dt.date)" 
                    ng-class="{\'text-center\':true, \'monthview-current\': dt.current&&!dt.selected&&!dt.hasEvent,\'monthview-secondary-with-event\': dt.secondary&&dt.hasEvent, \'monthview-primary-with-event\':!dt.secondary&&dt.hasEvent&&!dt.selected, \'monthview-selected\': dt.selected}">

                    <div ng-class="{\'text-muted\':dt.secondary}" ng-click="selectDate(dt.date)">
                        <p ng-repeat="person in persons">
                            {{person.id}}!
                        </p>
                        {{dt.label}}
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div ng-if="showEventDetail" class="event-detail-container" ng-show="showEventsDiv">
        <div class="scrollable" style="height: 200px">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="font-size: 18px; padding-left: 15px;">
                <i class="ion-calendar">&nbsp;
                </i>{{selectedDate.date |date:\'MM/dd/yyyy\'}}
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both">
            </div>
            <div class="item item-divider event">
                Events
            </div>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-fixed">
                <tr ng-repeat="event in selectedDate.events" ng-if="selectedDate.events">
                    <td ng-if="!event.allDay" class="monthview-eventdetail-timecolumn cal-date-txt">
                        {{event.startTime|date: \'HH:mm\'}} {{event.endTime|date: \'HH:mm\'}}
                    </td>

                    <td ng-if="event.allDay" class="monthview-eventdetail-timecolumn">
                        All day
                    </td>

                    <td class="event-detail cal-date-txt day" ng-click="eventSelected({event:event})">
                        {{event.title}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-if="!selectedDate.events">
                    <td class="no-event-label">No Events</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Array always shows ID single index.

Can someone explain and help me ? I can still not figure out why.

Comment: what is your problem

Comment: i have try to so id on calander but same array have repeate

Comment: PLEASE make an effort on understandability and spelling of your questions. We won't be able to help you otherwise.

Comment: <p ng-repeat="person in persons">{{person.id}}!</p> \n

Comment: i have array if u luking in the code

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ls7jyb2igkmz48f/Screenshot%20from%202016-08-05%2012%3A14%3A07.png?dl=0

Comment: What do you mean by 'ID single index'.. is it only showing 1 of the entries or does it repeat a single ID all the time?

Comment: ple check scrren shot

Comment: all entries of array show on single index

Comment: i think you expat proper date there. ?

Comment: according to ng repeat every new value insert on next rows or columns but in my case my array show all value on same row or columns like 1 2 3 4 not push on proper place

Comment: that would be because you repeat the person array in every `td` created by the `ng-repeat=dt in row track by dt,date`,

Comment: If you found the cause of the problem, please say it as an answer @Guinn.

Comment: yo are using person array out there , so its not a wrong visual , its just wrong data source you are using

Comment: can u explain how i can stop

Comment: your question doesn't really make clear what you expect instead of this behavior, hence why I didnt post an answer

Comment: u can share dopbox link no problem

Comment: Indeed there is nothing wrong and we do not know WHAT are you expecting. For every `dt in row` you are going through every `person in persons` which is a static array. So for each column you have all your person's ID: your `ng-repeat`s are imbricated ?

Comment: ok tell me friend how i can use propely ng-repaet

Comment: Is the person.id you want to show indexed at the same position as the $index of the parent's parent `ng-repeat=row in rows track by $index`? Meaning: if $index == 0, would you want to show $scope.persons[0].id?

Comment: i have alredy try this